# package Adw doesn't have EntryRow

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject, gtk4

I'm trying to make a boxed-list with an AdwEntryRow, following:

https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/libadwaita/doc/main/boxed-lists.html#boxed-lists

However I don't find this class in Adw

```
(Pdb) Adw
<IntrospectionModule 'Adw' from '/usr/lib64/girepository-1.0/Adw-1.typelib'>
(Pdb) [x for x in dir(Adw) if "Row" in x]
['ActionRow', 'ActionRowClass', 'ComboRow', 'ComboRowClass', 'ExpanderRow', 'ExpanderRowClass', 'PreferencesRow', 'PreferencesRowClass']
```

these are my dependencies so far:

```
pygobject       3.42.2 Python bindings for GObject Introspection
```

```
dnf list --installed | grep adwaita
adwaita-cursor-theme.noarch                          42.0-1.fc36                         @anaconda                                              
adwaita-gtk2-theme.x86_64                            3.28-14.fc36                        @fedora                                                
adwaita-icon-theme.noarch                            42.0-1.fc36                         @anaconda                                              
adwaita-qt5.x86_64                                   1.4.2-1.fc36                        @updates                                               
adwaita-qt6.x86_64                                   1.4.2-1.fc36                        @updates                                               
libadwaita.x86_64                                    1.1.4-1.fc36                        @updates                                               
libadwaita-qt5.x86_64                                1.4.2-1.fc36                        @updates                                               
libadwaita-qt6.x86_64                                1.4.2-1.fc36                        @updates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AdwEntryRow` was [introduced](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/libadwaita/doc/main/class.EntryRow.html) in libadwaita 1.2, and you seems to have 1.1.4 installed. That's the reason why you don't have `AdwEntryRow`.

Comment: Thank you I upgraded it with https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=2063175